# How to index different function within a Manipulate

Tags: code-review, code-request

I tried the following code and others to change the type of operation using `PopupMenu`:

```
ClearAll[plus, minus, index, hesap];
plus[x_, y_] := x + y;
minus[x_, y_] := x - y;
index = {plus, minus};

Manipulate[
   hesap[x, y],
   {{hesap, 1, "operation type"},  
   Thread[Range[Length[index]]->index], ControlType -> PopupMenu},  
   {x, 1, 10},
   {y, 1, 10}
 ]
```

This code does not work in the way I expect. What is missing in the code?

Comment: Change `index` to `index = {Plus, Subtract};` and change `Manipulate[hesap[x, y], ...` to `Manipulate[index[[hesap]][x, y], ...`

Comment: @flinty: I defined the {plus and minus} functions just to give an example. My original functions have different names and I like to recall them into `Manipulate` to do calculations. If I use {Plus, Subtract}, in effect I use `Mathematica` functions which I do not want to.

Comment: @flinty: I got your answer. You are right that I missed the linkage to pick the right index element. I used my original functions with correct linkage. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an association to avoid indexing e.g.

```
ops = AssociationThread[{"Add", "Subtract"}, {plus, minus}];

Manipulate[ops[op][x, y],
 {{op, "Add", "operation type"}, Keys@ops, ControlType -> PopupMenu},
 {x, 1, 10}, {y, 1, 10}]
```

Comment: Please see my comment above.

Comment: You can use whatever names you want, the names and the actual function names are independent and stored in the association.